# Power BI sum all values by default ignoring data modeling settings

Tags: powerbi

I'm working with a house prices dataset and I want to reproduce some plots from python in PowerBI

[image]

I'm loading the same dataset into power BI but I'm getting this result:

[image]

I have even't changed the settings to: Do Not sumarize. But still getting the same result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

to sum up the values you can create a measure; new measure = SUMX(Tabelle1,Tabelle1[precio_total) and then use this measure  as your y axis.